# UiBinder: Can UiFactory method be overriden?

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

Before asking a question i will shortly describe the context.
I have a Widget class which "outsources" ui implementation to a separate class (sth like below):

```
public class SimpleFilmWidget extends Composite implements FilmActivityControl {

    public static interface Ui {

        Panel getMainPanel();

        VoteWidget getVotePanel();

        InlineLabel getHaveNotSeenLabel();

        //...
    }
```

The actual widget class can get references to specific subfield widget/elements with use of the Ui class instance:

```
    Ui ui;

    public SimpleFilmWidget() {
        this(new DefaultUi());
    }

    public SimpleFilmWidget(Ui customUi) {

        assert customUi != null : "UI should not be null!!!";

        ui = customUi;

        initWidget(ui.getMainPanel());
    }
```

I provided the actual UI implementation with UiBinder that uses UiFactory for creation of another one complicated subwidget

```
class DefaultUi implements Ui {

    //...

    @UiFactory
    protected VoteWidget createVoteWidget(){

        return new VoteWidget(msg){

            @Override
            protected SetVoteEvent onSetVote(Star star, boolean fireEvents) {
                return clientWidget.onSetVote(super.onSetVote(star, fireEvents));
            }
        };
    }
```

And the question is:
When I provide the subclass of DefaultUi can the UiFactory method be overriden in a subclass not confusing UiBinder parser?

**EDIT:**

**UiFactory method should not be overriden** as uibinder sees both methods (the overridden and the overwriting) and becomes confused with two uifactories for the same type: `[ERROR] Duplicate factory in class SimpleFilmWidget.DefaultUi for type VoteWidget`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conclusion:

**UiFactory method should not be overriden** as uibinder sees both methods (the overridden and the overwriting) and becomes confused with two uifactories for the same type: `[ERROR] Duplicate factory in class SimpleFilmWidget.DefaultUi for type VoteWidget.`

*from comment to @Thomas Broyer:*
I suspect, it then calls the superclass'es UiFactory annotated method which is not what I want it to do. I left this issue, as workaround attitude is sufficing to me in this case.

Thanks for Your interest anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason it wouldn't be possible: UiBinder looks at the exposed API, and calls the method on the actual instance passed to `createAndBindUi`, this is just standard polymorphism.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I couldnt check if it works out at once, as i made bigger refactor and project does not build at the moment, so i wanted to ensure if my refactor goes the right way. I'll check if it works today.

Comment: Could you show the code you tried? (and yes, it's indeed possible the generator doesn't de-duplicate overridden methods; but I reading your question it didn't seem to me you'd face that issue)

Comment: I only mentioned that second Ui class extends DefaultUi without attaching a line of its code. So, there's OldUi class which extends DefaultUi - OldUi.createVoteWidget() overrides DefaultUi.createVoteWidget() so the ubinder finds two uifactory methods for the same type (the overriden is still visible to uibinder - i presume by reflection api but not checked uibinder's source code), which is obviously an error. Unfortunately I am not allowed to publish meaningful parts of source code for that project.

Comment: But the `UiBinder` interface is declared using `OldUi` then, not `DefaultUi`, right? So it's not just about call `createAndBindUi` with an instance of a subclass that overrides the `@UiFactory` method defined by the class used in the `UiBinder` interface declaration (not sure I'm clear here). In this case, yes, it seems like there's a bug in the generator. As a workaround, you could then have the `@UiFactory` being `final` and delegating to another method that can be overridden. Could you please [report the issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/entry) then?

Comment: You're right, the OldUi class overrides UiBinder template interface and factory method, createAndBindUi is called in OldUi constructor surely for proper uibinder instance. However the project does not use the newest gwt version.

Comment: But this what I was asking about- if I can override the UiFactory method :). Now after a try I know the answer is NO - :). And if I properly understood your last comment's intention - I should report that as a bug? :)

Comment: Absolutely. And I think I already know how to fix it ;-) ∕ Have you tried not re-annotating the method? (maybe that's what you were doing already; I'm curious to know the answer)

Comment: Yes, both (overriding and overwritten) were annotated with `@UiFactory`. Te overwriting signature was: `@UiFactory @Override protected VoteWidget createVoteWidget()` ...

Comment: You don't answer the question ;-) what if you remove the `@UiFactory` next to the `@Override` in `OldUi`? Does it work then?

Comment: I suspect, it then calls the superclass'es UiFactory annotated method which is not what I want it to do. I left this issue, as workaround attitude is sufficing to me in this case. Thanks for Your interest anyway.

Comment: Er, if it calls the superclass method and not the overridden one, then we have a Java problem (remember generators produce Java, that is then compiled to JS); or maybe the `@UiFactory` in the subclass didn't actually overrode the `@UiFactory` of the superclass, in which case the error was expected.